# Firebase-hosted fonts always come back 404

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a few font files in a static firebase (angular) app. I'm using what appears to be a valid app structure:

```
./firebase.json 

./dist/(all of my app)
```

My fonts are located in the dist folder:

```
./dist/path/to/fonts/font.woff
```

... Locally, the app works as expected, but when deployed, the response is always 404. I figure it has be:

1.) firebase deploy is ignoring these files

2.) A CORS issue?

Here's an example of what my firebase.json file looks like:

```
{
  "firebase": "my-firebase-app",
  "public": "dist",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ],
  "headers": [ {
    "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
    "headers" : [ {
      "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value" : "*"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

Not sure if this is a bug or just something I was missing, but the original font files were named *Foo-webfont.woff*. On a whim (read: desperation), I decided to rename them to just foo.woff, and voila, we have fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I found that names of font files were case insensitive on my PC and MAC but when I did firebase deploy --only hosting there were problems. Make sure the filenames care correct in your font-face css.

```
   `@font-face {
       font-family: 'sfuitext-bold';
         src: url('#{$fontsPath}/SFUIText-Semibold.ttf') format("truetype");
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
   }`
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't include the /public in the @font-face url
   Example: src: url("../../public/fonts/Burbank/burbank.ttf") to src: url("/fonts/Burbank/burbank.otf");
2. Change any format to .otf
   (I was using .ttf and when I changed it to .otf it worked for me)
3. If any special characters are present in the font name remove them and use a single name.
   Example: BurbankBigCondensed-Bold.otf to burbank.otf